# jQuery dynamically set href value of an anchor to the href value of another anchor using their class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hubspot

I have a dynamically generating search listing page on hubspot based on search term queries.

The HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="search-listing">
  a class="hs-search-results__title" href="www.something.com"><img src="Some image"></a>
  <a class="more-link">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Now the page has a few of these .search-listing divs. I want the href of the `more-link` inside each .search-listing take the value of the href in the `hs-search-results__title` link of each search-listing.

**Addition:**
This is the code that is used to give the value to the hs-search-results__title in the first place. Maybe this would be of help?

HTML:

```
<div class="hs-search-results2">
  <template class="hs-search-results__template">
    <li>
        <div class="hs-search-results__featured-image">
          <a href="#"><img src=""></a>
        </div>

      <a href="#" class="hs-search-results__title">Content Title</a>
      <p class="hs-search-results__description">Description</p>
       <p>
        <a class="more-link" href="#" style="color: #FFF!important">Read More</a>
       </p>
    </li>
  </template>
  <ul id="hsresults" class="hs-search-results__listing"></ul>
  <div class="hs-search-results__pagination" data-search-path="{{ site_settings.content_search_results_page_path }}">
    <a href="" class="hs-search-results__prev-page"></a>
    <a href="" class="hs-search-results__next-page"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var hsResultsPage = function(_resultsClass) {

    function buildResultsPage(_instance) {
        var resultTemplate = _instance.querySelector('.hs-search-results__template'),
            resultsSection = _instance.querySelector('.hs-search-results__listing'),
            searchPath = _instance.querySelector('.hs-search-results__pagination').getAttribute('data-search-path'),
            prevLink = _instance.querySelector('.hs-search-results__prev-page'),
            nextLink = _instance.querySelector('.hs-search-results__next-page');

        var searchParams =  new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.slice(1));

        function getTerm() {
            return searchParams.get('term') || "";
        }
        function getOffset() {
            return parseInt(searchParams.get('offset')) || 0;
        }
        function getLimit() {
            return parseInt(searchParams.get('limit'));
        }
        function addResult(title, url, description, featuredImage) {
            var newResult = document.importNode(resultTemplate.content, true);
            function isFeaturedImageEnabled() {
                if (newResult.querySelector('.hs-search-results__featured-image img')) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }

            newResult.querySelector('.hs-search-results__title').innerHTML = title;
            newResult.querySelector('.hs-search-results__title').href = url;
           newResult.querySelector('.hs-search-results__featured-image a').href = url;
            newResult.querySelector('.hs-search-results__description').innerHTML = description;
            if (typeof featuredImage !== 'undefined' && isFeaturedImageEnabled()) {
                newResult.querySelector('.hs-search-results__featured-image img').src = featuredImage;
            }
            resultsSection.appendChild(newResult);
        }
        function fillResults(results) {
            results.results.forEach(function(result, i){
                addResult(result.title, result.url, result.description, result.featuredImageUrl);
            });
        }
        function emptyPagination() {
            prevLink.innerHTML = "";
            nextLink.innerHTML = "";
        }
        function emptyResults(searchedTerm) {
            resultsSection.innerHTML =  "<div class=\"hs-search__no-results\"><p>Sorry. There are no results for \"" + searchedTerm + "\"</p>" +
                                        "<p>Try rewording your query, or browse through our site.</p></div>";
        }
        function setSearchBarDefault(searchedTerm) {
            var searchBars = document.querySelectorAll('.hs-search-field__input');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(searchBars, function(el){
                el.value = searchedTerm;
            });   
        }
        function httpRequest(term, offset) {
            var SEARCH_URL = "/_hcms/search?",
                requestUrl = SEARCH_URL + searchParams + "&analytics=true",
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open('GET', requestUrl, true);
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                      setSearchBarDefault(data.searchTerm);
                    if (data.total > 0) {
                        fillResults(data);
                        paginate(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        emptyResults(data.searchTerm);
                        emptyPagination();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.error('Server reached, error retrieving results.');
                }
            };
            request.onerror = function() {
                console.error('Could not reach the server.');
            };
            request.send();
        }
        function paginate(results) {
            var updatedLimit = getLimit() || results.limit;     

            function hasPreviousPage() {
                return results.page > 0;
            }
            function hasNextPage() {
                return results.offset <= (results.total - updatedLimit);
            }

            if (hasPreviousPage()) {
                var prevParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
                prevParams.set('offset', (results.page * updatedLimit) - parseInt(updatedLimit));
                prevLink.href = "/" + searchPath + "?" + prevParams; 
                prevLink.innerHTML = "&lt; Previous page";
            } 
            else {
                prevLink.parentNode.removeChild(prevLink);
            }

            if (hasNextPage()) {
                var nextParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
                nextParams.set('offset', (results.page * updatedLimit) + parseInt(updatedLimit));
                nextLink.href = "/" + searchPath + "?" + nextParams; 
                nextLink.innerHTML = "Next page &gt;";
            } 
            else {
                nextLink.parentNode.removeChild(nextLink);
            }
        }
        var getResults = (function() {
            if (getTerm()) {
                httpRequest(getTerm(), getOffset());
            }
            else {
                emptyPagination();
            }
        })();
    }
    (function() {
        var searchResults = document.querySelectorAll(_resultsClass);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(searchResults, function(el){
            buildResultsPage(el);
        });
    })();
}

if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    var resultsPages = hsResultsPage('.hs-search-results2');
} 
else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var resultsPages = hsResultsPage('.hs-search-results2');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the `search-listing` and find the corresponding element inside of the element to get/set the attribute.

Try the following way:

```js
$('.search-listing').each(function(){
  var searchHref = $(this).find('.hs-search-results__title').attr('href');
  $(this).find('.more-link').attr('href', searchHref)
});
```

```css
a img{
  width:25px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-listing">
  <a class="hs-search-results__title" href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></a>
  <a class="more-link">Read More</a>
</div>
<div class="search-listing">
  <a class="hs-search-results__title" href="https://google.com/"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-512.png"></a>
  <a class="more-link">Read More</a>
</div>
```